# Performing a distributed CUDA/OpenCL based password cracking

Tags: cuda, opencl, distributed-computing

Is there a way to perform a distributed (as in a cluster of a connected computers) CUDA/openCL based dictionary attack?

For example, if I have a one computer with some NVIDIA card that is sharing the load of the dictionary attack with another coupled computer and thus utilizing a second array of GPUs there?

The idea is to ensure a scalability option for future expanding without the need of replacing the whole set of hardware that we are using. (and let's say cloud is not an option)

Comment: For regular operation, you should not need to do password cracking.

Comment: What do you mean 'for regular operation'? we are a consulting firm that present password cracking check for our costumers, amongst other services.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the use case here. If you want to check if a password is good enough, you can check its plain text version at the moment it is entered - no need for a brute force dictionary attack to do this.

Comment: Excuse me, @PaŭloEbermann, but you obviously are not familiar with security professional services - there are many cases (i.e. unix systems that are not hardned properly, penetration testing, legacy systems, custom in-house developed application and much more scenarios) which a proper password cracking machine is essential. You may even follow some of the threads around here and see similar questions. Please cancel your downvote on the topic, it's misleading.

Comment: I have a rather primitive but effective setup for this: multiple computers with the same cracking software, but different dictionaries/rulesets on each computer so the cracking occurs in parallel.  I 'weighed' the dicts/rules by the GPU in each box so older GPUs have smaller number of combos to try in the same timeframe.   The problem is with merging back the results, as well as there's no easy way to keep removing the cracked hashes from the main list.  I tried it with having the main list on a shared network drive, but multiple programs trying to open it for writing cause issues.

Comment: Voting to close -- take away the words "password cracking" and this is a CS / queuing question. Belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: Migrated to the wrong site. I cannot re-migrate it. I'd suggest trying stackoverflow.

Comment: @Paulo - what dalimama is saying is that the plain text needs to be checked against a dictionary. I mean, that's one of the requisites for performing a good password check. Typical password checking software gives the green light to thinks like `Adm8n8str1t9r` or with known cribs (`syst3m`) with which to mount known-plaintext attacks. A good dictionary would contain plain text and alpha-to-num substituted text, and you would compare a pwd candidate (*and its substrings* of certain length) against the dictionary...

Comment: .. con't. That is, dalimama is not mounting a brute force attack. He/she is assessing that a password candidate has a very low probability of having its plain text *guessed* from its cyphertext via a brute force attack.

Comment: @luis.espinal: "Password cracking" sounds like running some algorithm on the password hash to find the matching password. I still don't see how this is necessary (or "useful") for any white-hat use case. (Have a look at [dalimama's other questions at security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/users/5896/dalimama?tab=questions):  ["we would like to have our very own password cracking machine"](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/8957/1396).)

Comment: Yeah, I see what the title says (password cracking), but that is not what was described in the post (nor what I described). So I'm not going by the title, but by the question. Though it is true that using 'password cracking' in the title is a bit disconcerting. The question on security.SE is also disconcerting to say the least (I highly doubt a client would be willing to ship its hashes to the cloud.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple master / slave work delegation problem. The master work server hands out to any connecting slave process a unit of work. Slaves work on one unit and queue one unit. When they complete a unit, they report back to the server. Work units that are exhaustively checked are used to estimate operations per second. Depending on your setup, I would adjust work units to be somewhere in the 15-60 second range. Anything that doesn't get a response by the 10 minute mark is recycled back into the queue.

For queuing, offer the current list of uncracked hashes, the dictionary range to be checked, and the permutation rules to be applied. The master server should be able to adapt queues per machine and per permutation rule set so that all machines are done their work within a minute or so of each other.

Alternately, coding could be made simpler if each unit of work were the same size. Even then, no machine would be idle longer than the amount of time for the slowest machine to complete one unit of work. Size your work units so that the fastest machine doesn't enter a case of resource starvation (shouldn't complete work faster than five seconds, should always have a second unit queued). Using that method, hopefully your fastest machine and slowest machine aren't different by a factor of more than 100x.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that it would be quite easy to write your own service that would do just this.

**Super Easy Setup**

Let's say you have some GPU enabled program X that takes a hash h as input and a list of dictionary words D, then uses the dictionary words to try and crack the password. With one machine, you simply run X(h,D).

If you have N machines, you split the dictionary into N parts (D_1, D_2, D_3,...,D_N). Then run P(x,D_i) on machine i.

This could easily be done using SSH. The master machine splits the dictionary up, copies it to each of the slave machines using SCP, then connects to the slaves and tells them to run the program.

**Slightly Smarter Setup**

When one machine cracks the password, they could easily notify the master that they have completed the task. The master then kills the programs running on the other slaves.

Comment: That's a good approach, agreed, but it still is not the same as load balancing with a consolidated distributed cluster. That password hashes are not consolidated and the simple cutting the dictionary into N parts isn't accurately balancing in terms of run-time because of the different attacking schemes and substition rules of a dictionary agains a rules file (e.g. JtR's single-mode, oclHashcat's rules files). You can fix it ad-hoc, and I really appreciate you answering me, but it won't be the same as an appropriate truly-distributed solution.

Comment: @dalimama, agreed. That is why I named them **Super Easy Setup** and **Slightly Smarter Setup**. Load balancing strategies will greatly depend upon your goal. Is your goal to crack a single hash (say root) or as many hashes as possible? Do individual hashes have priorities? Do individual hash files have priority rankings? In your case, I'd expect that these goals/requirements will vary from client to client. Then, to develop such a system, I expect that you will have to dive deep into the theory of distributed systes. Sounds like an interesting MS thesis though :)